# How can I increase an image's resolution without it getting pixelated?

Tags: java, image-processing

I'm wondering if there are algorithms that can take, say, a 100x70 image and scale it up to 200x140 without obvious pixelation?  These images may be photographs, or they may contain text or logos.

Ideally I'd like an open source Java library for this, but I could also implement an algorithm myself if it wasn't too complicated.

Comment: You can do that with normal Java means. Mathematically it is not impossible without some unsharpness. Keys: BufferedImage.getGraphics, Graphics.drawImage, RenderingHints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look [here](http://tech-algorithm.com/articles/bilinear-image-scaling/) : it explains about bilinear image scaling which smooths the image rather than pixelizing it. A java source code is included.

also try [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/) : it includes source code in java

Comment: "enhances" is a really poor wording since to me it sounds like the upscaled image is in some way "better" than the original. And it is not. I'd rephrase that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://code.google.com/p/java-image-scaling/